# require file doesn't exist until refresh

Tags: php

I have a require line in my php script.

```
require_once('../main.inc.php');
```

every once in a while, when I load a page, I get a message 'failed to open stream. no such file or directory'

But when I hit refresh, the page loads just fine.

What might be happening that the script can't seem to find the file until I simply refresh?

I am really hitting the error at this point before I use the require/include

```
if(!file_exists('../main.inc.php')) die('Fatal error
```

Comment: does your main.inc.php include other `require_one` calls or `include`s ?

Comment: try this `print_r(get_included_files());` This returns an array of all included files. Probably the file has been included or is also included in a function or another class as well.

Comment: Do you use opcache? Disable Opcache once.

Comment: Check the webserver logs. It should give a complete error stating what file didn't exist and why - perhaps it exists, but you didn't have permission to use it.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
include('../main.inc.php');
```

Comment: Now I am running into a problem, that it seems the file is not being included still, because the next line fails. but when I refresh, the page loads properly